# Ruby on Rails retrieve and display data according to user, e.g. retrieve all reviews created by one user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, admin

In my Ruby on Rails application users are able to leave reviews for products, and then the administrator can view all reviews. What I want to be able to do is make it so that an administrator can still see all reviews left by everyone but a normal user can only view their own reviews and not everyone elses. Is there a simple way I can do this without using java?

Below is my index.html.erb that displays all reviews by everyone.

```
<div class="centre-content"> 
   <div class="main-title">All reviews:</div>

    <table>
       <tr>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Review text</th>
          <th>No of stars</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>

      <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
      <tr>
          <td><%= review.product.title %></td>
          <td><%= review.user.name %></td>
          <td><%= review.review_text.truncate(35) %></td>
          <td><%= review.no_of_stars %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', review %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_review_path(review) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', review, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
     </tr>
   <% end %>
  </table>

 <br />

 <%= link_to 'Back', :back %>
</div>
```

application.html.erb where the administrator can click to view all reviews:

```
<% if admin? %>                     
                    <li> <%= link_to "Users", "" , :class => active_menu("users") %> 
                    <ul>
                        <li> <%= link_to "Users" , users_path %> </li>  
                        <li> <%= link_to "Edit profile" , edit_user_path(session[:user_id]) %> </li>
                    </ul>
                    <li> <%= link_to "Categories", categories_path , :class => active_menu("categories") %>
                    <li> <%= link_to "Reviews", reviews_path , :class => active_menu("reviews") %>
    <% end %>
```

reviews_controller.rb:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /reviews
  # GET /reviews.json
  def index
    @reviews = Review.all
  end

  # GET /reviews/1
  # GET /reviews/1.json
  def show
  end

  def new
    if logged_in?
    existing_review = Review.find_by_user_id_and_product_id(session[:user_id], params[:id])
      if existing_review == nil
      @review = Review.new(product_id: params[:id], 
                                user_id: User.find(session[:user_id]).id)
      session[:return_to] = nil
      else
        redirect_to edit_review_path(existing_review.id)
      end
    else
      session[:return_to] = request.url
      redirect_to login_path, alert: "You need to login to write a review"
    end
   end

  # GET /reviews/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    if @review.save
        product = Product.find(@review.product.id)
        redirect_to product, notice: 'Your review was successfully added.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.update(review_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @review, notice: 'Review was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reviews/1
  # DELETE /reviews/1.json
  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reviews_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def displays
    product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @reviews = product.reviews
    if @reviews.empty?
      redirect_to product, notice: "No reviews - as yet ..."
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:product_id, :user_id, :review_text, :no_of_stars)
    end
end
```

reviews.rb model:

```
   class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :user

    validates :review_text, :presence => { :message => "Review text: cannot be blank ..."}
    validates :review_text, :length =>   {:maximum => 2000, :message => "Review text: maximum length 2000 characters"} 

    validates :no_of_stars, :presence => { :message => "Stars: please rate this book ..."}
end
```

Is there anyway I can make it so that a user only views their own reviews?

Comment: In your controller, you can do stg like this i think : @reviews.select { |s| s.user_id == current_user.id } unless admin?. current_user you dont ahve now but you should, instead of relying on the session id. Otherwise wrong people could see others reviews just by changing their id in the session.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller display method, you can do stg like this i think :

`def display
        product = Product.find(params[:id])
        @reviews = product.reviews.select! { |s| s.user_id == current_user.id } unless admin?
    ....
    end`

That way, only admin will have all reviews, and others users will only see their own reviews (with theirs ids)

you dont have current_user method but it es explained well in this tutorial :

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#sec-current_user

it is the same as session[:id] but in a well ordered manner.

Ps: i'm not sur about the s.user_id ... don't remember the exact syntax but should be it.

Another way : 
you could take the reviews for this specific product id and then filter out by the user id.

```
`@reviews = Reviews.find_by_product_id(params[:product_id]).select { |r| r.user_id == current_user.id }`
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I've just tried that and have placed it in the displays method but I get the following error:

NoMethodError in ReviewsController#displays

private method `select' called for nil:NilClass

Comment: Using this line instead:     @reviews = Review.select { |s| s.user_id == session[:user_id] } unless admin? The error message is solved, but this doesn't allow a user to view only their reviews and an admin to view all reviews as still only all reviews are shown?

Comment: This errors means that your @reviews variable is null. You never had this error with your original version ? because you are doing `@reviews.empty?` , it is the same thing, if @reviews is null it should raise an error too. Anyway, I don't think your changes is good because it takes review directly from the Review class, that means you will get ALL reviews for that user, but also for ALL products !

Comment: I'm a bit old on the subject but you should definitly read the tutorial link I gave you. It explains in simple term & gradually all the rails basics (including association, you can skip directly to the micropost chapter)

Comment: No I wasn't getting an error before @reviews.empty? it could just be that I'm not placing your code in the correct place, would you mind showing me in your answer where you think it should go in the displays to make sure I've got it right?

Comment: I've added the beginning of the function. Plus another equivalent way.

Comment: Thanks for adding it to your answer, the first way you've said doesn't make a difference, it still shows all the reviews for the customer rather than just their own. And the second answer has the error: private method `select' called for nil:NilClass

Comment: Can you show what do you use to get the current user id ? do you have implemented the current_user method or do you use stg else ?

Comment: I use: session[:user_id] Does that help with your solution?

Comment: Mh... Does it shows ALL reviews (for every product) or at least it shows all reviews for the particular product the user is viewing ?